# Is there any option to have a Drop down on Column names in SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Is there any option to have a Drop down on Column names in SSRS report.

For example,  We have ENO,ENAME,PHONE,EMAILID,CITY columns in SSRS report and So by default when we open SSRS report we should see only ENO, ENAME, CITY these columns and other columns should be hidden. But when required we need to populate other 2 columns as well.

So is there way to do it in SSRS report to Auto hide the columns and have it report whenever its required.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by hiding column based on parameter values but it's messy as there will be whitespace left where the column should be. That might be OK for your scenario but a more flexible way to do it is to reorganise the data in the dataset query.

Here, I've put some sample data together

```
-- this is just to setup some data and will not be required in your report dataset query
declare @t table ( ENO int, ENAME varchar(20), PHONE varchar(20), EMAILID varchar(35), CITY varchar(20))
insert into @t values 
(1, 'Dave', '12345-6789', 'Dave@LondonOffice.com', 'London'),
(2, 'Bob' , '23456-7890', 'Bob@ParisOffice.com', 'Paris'),
(3, 'Mary', '34567-8901', 'Mary@NewYorkOffice.com', 'New York'),
(4, 'Jane', '45678-9012', 'Jane@MilanOffice.com', 'Milan'),
(5, 'John', '56789-0123', 'John@MunichOffice.com', 'Munich'),
(6, 'Alex', '67890-1234', 'Alex@MadridOffice.com', 'Madrid')

-- The following is required inthe dataset query swapping out "@t" for you real table name

SELECT * FROM
    (
        SELECT ENO, 'ENAME' as Property, 1 as ColSort, ENAME as PropValue FROM @t 
        UNION ALL SELECT ENO, 'PHONE' as Property, 4 as ColSort, PHONE as PropValue FROM @t 
        UNION ALL SELECT ENO, 'EMAILID' as Property, 3 as ColSort, EMAILID as PropValue FROM @t 
        UNION ALL SELECT ENO, 'CITY' as Property, 2 as ColSort, CITY as PropValue FROM @t 
    ) u 
    WHERE Property IN (@properties)
```

The above code, in my example is all in the dataset query but you will only need the last section, changing references to `@t` to your real table.

What we're doing is turning every column into a row and also adding a ColSort column so you can control what order the columns appear in the report. You could use `UNPIVOT` but that relies on the column datatypes being the same and makes it harder to add the column sort order.

Ignoring the `WHERE` clause for now, this gives us the following output

[image]

So, create a new report and add dataset that produces the results as above but make sure you add the `WHERE` clause as per the code example.

This is automatically add a parameter called `properties` to your report.

Edit the parameter and select "Allow Multiple Values".

Set the available values to the names or your columns, you can use a different label if you like, for example.

[image]

Now set the default values (ENO is always present so no need to add that)

[image]

Next, add a Matrix control to your report. Drag the ENO field to the rows placeholder, the Property field to the columns placeholder and the PropValue to the data placeholder.

Now double-click the "Property" column group and change the Sort BY to "ColSort"

[image]

That's it...

When the report is first run we get this..

[image]

We can then change whatever we like in the column selection parameter and hit view report again, for example.

[image]